# Is Visual FoxPro/FoxWeb Compatible with Ajax Push Engine (APE)?

Tags: ajax, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I'm researching how to set up an Ajax Push Engine (APE) but my first question is if Visual FoxPro9 / FoxWeb Server environment will work with an APE.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the simple APE API only has built in support for MySQL.
So, unless there is a way to access a FoxPro table by ODBC, I would say that FoxPro is not supported. :(